# Array.push() only to specific index of an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm setting up an object with year objects, month arrays, and days that are arrays of post objects. When I try to push data to `postData[year][month][date]`, it pushes to all the date arrays in `month`.

```js
let postData = {}

const addPosts = (year, month, newPosts) => {
  postData[year] = postData[year] || {}
  postData[year][month] = postData[year][month] || Array(30).fill([])
  postData[year][month][0].push('post')

  return postData
}
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "2020": {
    "4": [
      [
        "post"
      ],
      [
        "post"
      ],
      [
        "post"
      ],
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there something about .push() I'm not understanding or is there a limit to the number of indexes you can .push() into?

Answer (score 5):

This issue happens because you have assigned the same empty array `[]` as a reference to all of them like `Array(30).fill([])`. So, when you modify any one of them, it also updates each one of them like:

```js
const arr = Array(2).fill([])
arr[0].push('post')
console.log(arr) //=> [["post"], ["post"]]
```

In this demo, you can't see this properly but if you open chrome console then you can see the actual result.

To fix this issue you can simply use `.map()` method and assign a new array `[]` to each item in the main array like:

```js
const arr = Array(2).fill().map(a => []);
arr[0].push('post')
console.log(arr) //=> [["post"], []]
```

Comment: Or simply `Array.from({length:30}, ()=>[])` this will do the trick as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, did not know that `[]` inside the `.fill` method would infer the same reference.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you so much for clarifying - I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I cannot explain, the answer was to forego `push()`, and instead set the value of that index to a new array:

```
let postData = {}

const addPosts = (year, month, newPosts) => {
  postData[year] = postData[year] || {}
  postData[year][month] = postData[year][month] || Array(30).fill([])
  postData[year][month][0] = [...postData[year][month][0], 'post']

  return postData
}
```

I'm going to leave this up for anyone in the future Googling for **strange Array push behaviors in React, js .push() not working**